# If $f\in A_k(V)$ and $g\in A_l(V)$ show $i_v(f\wedge g)=i_vf\wedge g+(-1)^kf\wedge i_vg$ - I've got the gist, not sure how to write

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds

If $f\in A_k(V)$ and $g\in A_l(V)$ show $i_v(f\wedge g)=i_vf\wedge g+(-1)^kf\wedge i_vg$

With $A_k(V)$ being the vector space of alternating k-tensors.

for $f\in A_k(V)$ for some $v\in V$ we define $i_vf\in V_{k-1}(V)$ by $i_vf(v_1,v_2,...,v_{k-1})=f(v,v_1,v_2,...,v_{k-1})$

**My "answer"**

This is similar to combinatorics, we all know Pascal's relation: $(n+1)Cr=nC(r-1)+nCr$ the proof is simple, given a set of $\{a_1,...,a_n,b\}$ (b is the $n+1$th thing) and tasked with choosing r things from it

We may have b then $r-1$ things from the remaining $n$, or!

We do not have b then $r$ things from the remaining $n$

I think that's at play here.

**why:**

Well $$f\wedge g(a_1,...,a_{k+l})=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\text{sign}(\sigma)f(a_{\sigma_1},...,a_{\sigma_k})g(a_{\sigma_{k+1}},...,a_{\sigma_{k+l}})
$$

So $$i_v(f\wedge g)(a_1,...,a_{k+l-1})=f\wedge g(v,a_1,...,a_{k+l-1})$$

For a permutation of $\{v,a_1,...,a_{k+l-1}\}$ either v is an argument to f or it is not. If the $v$ is an argument to $f$ then we're somewhere with the $i_vf\wedge g$ part. Otherwise the $v$ is one of g's argument.

This is what I mean by "gist" of argument, I'm struggling to form this into the expression I want as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions $\iota_v(f\wedge g)$ and $\iota_vf\wedge g+(-1)^kf\wedge\iota_vg$ are linear in $f$ and $g$ so it suffices to prove the claim on basis elements. That is, assume $f=\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^k$ and $g=\alpha^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+l}$ where each of $\alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^{k+l}$ are all $1$-forms. One way to prove the claim is to use the fact that $$\iota_v(\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^n)=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1}\alpha^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{i-1}\wedge\alpha^{i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^n$$ You can prove this fact by recalling that $$\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^n(v,v_2,\dots,v_n)=\text{det}\left[\begin{array}{c c c c}\alpha^1(v)&\alpha^1(v_2)&\dots&\alpha^1(v_n)\\\alpha^2(v)&\alpha^2(v_2)&\dots&\alpha^2(v_n)\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\alpha^n(v)&\alpha^n(v_2)&\dots&\alpha^n(v_n)\end{array}\right]$$ and performing cofactor expansion along the first column. We have by definition, $\iota_v(f\wedge g)=\iota_v(\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+l}),$ while by the above this is equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+l}(-1)^{i-1}\alpha^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{i-1}\wedge\alpha^{i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+l}$$which is $$\begin{array}{c}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1}\alpha^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{i-1}\wedge\alpha^{i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k}\right)\wedge\alpha^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+l}\\ + \ \ \ \alpha^{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{l}(-1)^{k+i-1}\alpha^{k+i}(v)\alpha^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+i-1}\wedge\alpha^{k+i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+l}\right)\end{array}$$ which is $$\begin{array}{c}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1}\alpha^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{i-1}\wedge\alpha^{i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k}\right)\wedge\alpha^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+l}\\ +\ \ \ (-1)^k\alpha^{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{l}(-1)^{i-1}\alpha^{k+i}(v)\alpha^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+i-1}\wedge\alpha^{k+i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^{k+l}\right)\end{array}$$ which is

$$\iota_vf\wedge g+(-1)^kf\wedge\iota_vg$$

Comment: I've downvoted and I hate to do it, this is borderline, on the one hand great answer, BUT it doesn't do it in the method stated. You've also assumed it's decomposable, which is the next question in the source this was taken from. I'm really sorry.

Comment: No worries, I mostly wanted to recall how to prove it just for myself. I'm not sure what you mean by assuming it is decomposable though?

Comment: The next question is to show that a tensor can be expressed as the wedge product of tenors (something I am stuck with, it's almost trivial, but writing it in a way that I am happy with ... far from it!)